# How to find those rows which are different on certain columns among to dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I am having two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'Date':['2024-01-01', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-03', '2024-01-04', '2024-01-05'], 'Value1':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Value2':[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Date':['2024-01-30', '2024-01-30', '2024-01-30', '2024-01-30'], 'Value1':[1, 2, 7, 4], 'Value2':[5, 6, 7, 9]})
```

Here is how `df1` looks like :

```
  ID        Date  Value1  Value2
0  A  2024-01-01       1       5
1  B  2024-01-02       2       6
2  C  2024-01-03       3       7
3  D  2024-01-04       4       8
4  E  2024-01-05       5       9
```

Here is how `df2` looks like :

```
  ID        Date  Value1  Value2
0  A  2024-01-30       1       5
1  B  2024-01-30       2       6
2  C  2024-01-30       7       7
3  D  2024-01-30       4       9
```

Now my purpose is to find out which two rows between these two dataframes having different values on columns `['Value1', 'Value2']` based on `'ID'` column. In this case, the rows with `'ID'`s as `'C'` and `'D'`. Note, the `'Date'` column is different, but I do not need to compare them.

Any thoughts about a neat solution without marshal through the whole dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Anti Join**

I accomplished this with an `anti join` to determine the `IDs` that do not match between the two.

```
outer = df1.merge(df2,how='outer',on=['ID','Value1','Value2'],indicator=True)
anti_join = outer[(outer._merge=='left_only')].drop('_merge',axis=1)
anti_join = anti_join[df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])]
```

Comment: This will include ID='E' which I do not need.

Comment: @xymzh what about with the filter i just added on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` and `query` to find the differences:

```
>>> (df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='inner')  # use outer if needed
        .query('(Value1_x != Value1_y) | (Value2_x != Value2_y)')

  ID      Date_x  Value1_x  Value2_x      Date_y  Value1_y  Value2_y
2  C  2024-01-03         3         7  2024-01-30         7         7
3  D  2024-01-04         4         8  2024-01-30         4         9
```

Same without unwanted columns:

```
cols = ['ID', 'Value1', 'Value2']
out = (pd.merge(df1[cols], df2[cols], on='ID', how='inner')
         .query('(Value1_x != Value1_y) | (Value2_x != Value2_y)'))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  ID  Value1_x  Value2_x  Value1_y  Value2_y
2  C         3         7         7         7
3  D         4         8         4         9
```